# MS Word 2016 Fillable forms

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I am creating an MS Word 2016 doc with Fillable Form and I am stuck here. I have an field where I want to enter only the digit. I also want to limit the length of the phone number to 10 character. If the user tries to enter any alphabet or special character, or if the length exceeds 10 , the user should not be able to do so.

[image: Picture]

Comment: What research have you done, and what have you tried? You might find some of the results from [Googling "MS Word Fillable Form Input Validation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MS+Word+fillable+form+input+validation&oq=ms+word+fillable+form+input+validation) to be enlightening.

Comment: I think this might help you [Link 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/is-there-a-way-to-do-number-format-in-a-fillable/e24ba9c0-1175-40cc-b0bd-ba18f5a4979e), and if you have some knowledge of VB then these forums will help you to understand the code and you can use these codes to code your *Text Box (Active X Controls)* in **Legacy Tools** in *Controls Section* of *Developer menu*. Links to the forums is in next comment.

Comment: Forums Links: [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801430/only-accept-digits-for-textbox), [Link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506105/only-allow-numeric-values-in-the-textbox), [Link 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969824/vb-net-need-text-box-to-only-accept-numbers)

Comment: Thank you. I was not using right word to do Google search for this. It has been great help. Thanks a lot.